# WebSocket -- Client -- node js

Tags: node.js, websocket

Мне нужно чтобы приложение подключилось к уже запущенному серверу к машине в локальной сети. Я пытался использовать код, что используется в браузере для коннекта с WebSocketServer.

```
let socket = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.88.223:9002");
socket.onopen = function (e) { // ОТПРАВИТЬ СЕРВЕРУ КОННЕКТ
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({action: "OnlinePC"}));
};
```

я получаю ошибку: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите как я могу подключиться к серверу.

Comment: Зачем вам вебсокеты при общении двух серверов между собой?)

Comment: `import WebSocket from 'ws';` или `const WebSocket = require('ws');`